# Where does MariaDB `mysql` client save the output file of a select statement?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, into-outfile, select-into-outfile

From this documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/select-into-outfile/

I ran

```
MariaDB []> select ... into outfile 'leads_ny.csv';
Query OK, 6674 rows affected (0.47 sec)
```

Now I can't find the file. I looked in the current working directory, the directory I started `mysql` in, my home directory, I even ran `find` on each of those, but I can't find it. I'm currently running `$ find / -name leads_ny.csv`.

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.30-MariaDB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! Was in the DB data directory

```
/var/lib/mysql/dbname/leads_ny.csv
```

Comment: You can specify a full path in the `OUTFILE` part but be aware that this may be restricted by your server settings. Also be aware that large CSV output files may exhaust your database partition's free space and cause issues, so always check that you've got enough free space before proceeding for large tables.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS Sierra the folder was `/usr/local/var/mysql`